# How to block urls that request for robots.txt in lighttpd?

Tags: lighttpd, robots.txt

We have a dedicated development server which runs only test PHP applications on a public network.
We have setup session-based authentication for the site.

The issue we have is there are lots of 404s logged in access log for robots.txt.
So, We want to block/ignore these requests on the lighttpd to save some bandwidth.

How can we achieve this in lighttpd/1.4.31 ?

Comment: wouldn't it be better to put a dummy robots.txt file?

Comment: @WaleedHamra, But isnt putting a dummy robots.txt file also a part of bandwidth.
The applications on the server takes around 150K requests per day.
So, i suppose serving a dummy file will use 150K*1K of bandwidth.
Am I Right?

Comment: a 1 byte file will generate 150K bytes of data... much smaller than a complete 404 page, if your server serves one.

Comment: Why are search engines crawling your development server in the first place?!?

Comment: WaleedHamra,oh ok, didnt think of it that way.
Thanks for pointing.  
MichaelHampton, no idea, i have a domain via which all the applications are accessed, could that be the reason?